# Spring drop down not working

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu

i am using spring mvc,

```
  <form:select  class="form-control" id ="cmsphyexamtesttype_cmsPhysicalExamCategory_id"          path="cmsPhysicalExamCategory.id">
                                            <form:option value="0" label="--- Please select the Category  ---"/>
                                            <form:options items="${cmsphyexamtestcategorys}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
                                            </form:select>
```

html code

```
 <select id="cmsphyexamtesttype_cmsPhysicalExamCategory_id" name="cmsPhysicalExamCategory.id" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="0">--- Please select the Category  ---</option>
                                            <option value="2">Genaral</option><option value="3">EYE</option><option value="4">HENT</option><option value="5">CHEST</option>
                                            </select>
```

this one is working fine with new form , but in edit mode,it is not working do you have any idea it gives selected value while rendered to editing mode, i am new to spring mvc, is there any thing wrong with this code?

Comment: Code looks good for me. What do You mean by "edit mode" ?

Comment: While rendering the same form again for editing purpose , i have the problem mvc sets the selected attribute by default , and it is not changing, value is changing but selected attribute is not changing so changed drop down value is not storing

Comment: Please post the controller method that is used to populate the form in "edit mode"

Answer (score 0):

You are path binding the drop down value to the

```
cmsPhysicalExamCategory.id
```

So, the selected value will be retained in the form when you recall the form again for some other operation like 'edit.

You can change the value in the drop down and the new value will be path binded to the model. Here, its not getting binded. It may be because of the error in path bind/form submit.

Please post the form submit code/controller code for more help.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I get is that you have drop down and on submitting again , you want to render the same form, you are getting the change value but drop down value still persist to the default , first attribute of drop down, and you want to have the attribute same as value, in case this is the elaborated issue, you need to explicitly check in list for what value you want to select and set the attribute as **Selected**.